# Recurrence iteration method solve

Tags: iteration, array-algorithms

hi i have this recurrence: how to solve?
a)  Solve the following recurrence using the iteration method and give an asymptotic running time:
T(0)=0   and   T(n)=10 +T(n-1),   for n ≥ 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic programming technique to iteratively solve the problem:

```
define results[n+1];
results[0] = 0;

for (i = 1; i < n + 1 ) {
      set  results[i] to 10 + results[i-1] 
}

Tn = results[n];
```

Running time for the above algorithm will ***n***.